# htaccess multiple rewrite rules stacking

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been searching for a while now, I tried a bunch of things, but nothing seems to be working for me.

I have this code in .htaccess in folder *www. - .com/p/*:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+)$ $1+$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1+$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule p/(.*) index.php?w=$1 [L,QSA]
```

As you see, I basically tried to stack the rules on each other, like if it was a passing variable. But it does seem impossible to do like that ...
For example, I could have a link ending with *.../p/whatever/does/not/matter* and I want to rewriterule it to *.../index.php?w=whatever+does+not+matter*
And it really needs to be dynamic, that is - I cannot just write a rule for every folder and be done with it. The folders might change without me knowing. But they always have to be redirected.
*(Don't mind the R,L,QSA - it's probably incorrect)*

I am struggling with this for a few days now, which is absurd.
Please, could you help me?
Thank you for every input.

Comment: You could probably make this a lot easier, if you just passed the value `whatever/does/not/matter` to your index.php, and then did the replacing of slashes with spaces in there …

Comment: @CBroe, you mean redirecting in index ? That could be a problem, since there is a header('Location: ') redirect already and it might occur that they would collide resulting in an error.

Comment: No, I meant rewrite to `index.php?w=whatever/does/not/matter` using mod_rewrite. Replacing the slashes in that parameter value inside your PHP script then is a rather trivial issue, whereas replacing characters using RewriteRule can get rather messy.

Comment: You need to describe the actual problem you are trying to solve. The question would seem to have nothing to do with "stacking" rules, but that you want to perform a search & replace on the requested URL-path (and to pass this as a query string). However, why not simply do the search/replace in your PHP script, as suggested?

Comment: @CBroe I have never considered mod_rewrite to be an option... I will look into it, thank you !